# ssh password less connectivity issue

Tags: ssh

Facing issue while getting output from another server. Passwordless connectivity is available.

Suppose when I am doing `df -kh` with below, its working (doing ssh & getting o/p from another server)

```
[user1@meylvmacs01 ~]$ssh user1@10.175.59.130  df -kh

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              99G   11G   83G  12% /
tmpfs                  32G   76K   32G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             200M  264K  200M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4              55G  8.3G   44G  16% /opt/SP
/dev/sda5              55G   30G   23G  58% /var/SP
172.22.27.141:/root_vdm_1/GDSP_Commmon_NAS
                      493G  227G  266G  47% /var/SP/nfs/gdsp
[m2muser@meylvmacs01 ~]$
```

But when I am doing below, I am getting the following error:

```
ssh user1@10.175.59.130 sqlplus SOAF_PUBLISHER/S_PUBLISHER_SOAF@OSBS1
```

although  sqlplus exe  is present in another server at below directory `/opt/SP/apps/instantclient_11_2/bin`

```
[user1@meylvmacs01 tmp]$ssh user1@10.175.59.130 sqlplus SOAF_PUBLISHER/S_PUBLISHER_SOAF@OSBS1
bash: sqlplus: command not found
```

What is option that should be passed to get this executed successfully?

Comment: Could be an issue with `PATH`. Try with absolute path, like `ssh user1@10.175.59.130 /opt/SP/apps/instantclient_11_2/bin/sqlplus SOAF_PUBLISHER/S_PUBLISHER_SOAF@OSBS1`

Comment: No above suggested giving error :                                                                          [m2muser@meylvmacs01 ~]$ssh m2muser@10.175.59.130 /opt/SP/apps/instantclient_11_2/bin/sqlplus SOAF_PUBLISHER/S_PUBLISHER_SOAF@OSBS1DUB
/opt/SP/apps/instantclient_11_2/bin/sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory                                                                                                          is there is any way to get this execute using xargs or exec ...i tried but could not succeed

Answer (score 0):

You have application, that is not integrated in the system (installed in the different than default directory, loading libraries from non-default paths), which causes some trouble if it is not configured well. It is probably configured in `.bashrc` or so, but this is mostly skipped in case you run just a command and not interactive shell. There are two options:

- Use the standard input to get the command to the server:

  ```
  echo "sqlplus SOAF_PUBLISHER/S_PUBLISHER_SOAF@OSBS1" | ssh -tt user1@10.175.59.130
  ```
- Fix the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable initiation in `~/.bashrc` (or other startup files) so they will not be skipped for non-interactive commands. It generally contains something like

  ```
  # If not running interactively, don't do anything
  case $- in
      *i*) ;;
        *) return;;
  esac
  # your commands ...
  ```

  Just add the modification `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` above it and try again.